# Deleting Every Third Node in a Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes, doubly-linked-list

I have a function that deletes every third node in a linked list:

```
void tricimate()
    {
    node * toDelete = head->next->next;
    while (toDelete != NULL)
    {
        if (toDelete->next == NULL)
        {
            tail = tail->prev;
            tail->next = NULL;
            delete toDelete;
            break;
        }
        node * ahead = toDelete->prev;
        node * behind = toDelete->next;
        ahead->next = behind;
        behind->prev = ahead;
        delete toDelete;
        toDelete = behind->next->next;
    }

}
```

It works but when I try to add the node with the value of 47, it doesn't add it. I have this:

```
29 7 2 3 31 37
```

When I should have this:

```
29 7 2 3 31 37 47
```

This is my code for adding a new node to the back of the linked list:

```
void addBack(int x)
{
    node * newItem = new node;
    if (head == NULL && tail == NULL)
    {
        newItem->data = x;
        newItem->next = NULL;
        newItem->prev = NULL;
        head = newItem;
        tail = newItem;
    }
    else
    {
        newItem->data = x;
        newItem->next = NULL;
        newItem->prev = tail;
        tail->next = newItem;
        tail = newItem;
    }
}
```

I don't understand what is wrong because the addBack was working before. But after I used the tricimate function it stopped working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems you forgot to change `tail` after deleting nodes. Note that your code has several other potential bugs (e.g. if there is only one node and you call `tricimate`, the first line will cause a runtime error).

Comment: And you have an undefined behavior here `node * toDelete = head->next->next;`  if `head` or `head->next` is `NULL`.

Comment: @WhatsUp My proffessor told us to assume that the linked list had at least three nodes in it and where exactly am I not changing tail?

Comment: @E.Reyes This code you've written to delete every third node seems overdone.  Why not just have a counter, incrementing it as you go through the list.  If `counter %3 == 0`, delete the current node that you're on?  Not only would that be easier to code, anyone could understand right away what is being done.  Looking at the code you posted, it is very difficult to tell what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your `tricimate` function, it looks like a case of overthinking things, and that resulted in "overcoding".

To delete every third node (assuming the linked list has at least 3 nodes), the code could just set a counter to 1, increment the counter in a loop, and if the counter is evenly divisble by 3, delete that node.

What you should do is write a function that deletes any node from the list (call it `remove_node`).  If you have that, then the function to delete every third node becomes simple:

```
void tricimate()
{
   int counter = 1;
   node* curNode = head;
   while (curNode)
   {
      node *nextNode = curNode->next;  // save for the next iteration
      if ( counter % 3 == 0 )  // if we're on the node we want to delete...
         remove_node(curNode);  // remove it.
      ++counter;              // increment count
      curNode = nextNode;     // go to next node.
   }   
}
```

Note that I did not implement the `remove_node` function.  I do not know how the rest of your linked list is implemented, so did not want to assume too much about it if I were to attempt to write the `remove_node` function.  But at the very least, it should have a function to remove a node -- if not, it is lacking basic functionality that any linked list implementation should have.

Comment: Can't upvote the basic message of this enough. Any time you have a Do_1 and a Do_N, Do_N should be implemented in terms of Do_1 and only changed to a specialized case after profiling has demonstrated significant and required advantages. If they are not required, maintaining simple code should win the day.

Comment: I used your function but the new node with 47 is still not being added to the back of the linked list. Is there something wrong with my addBack function?

Comment: @E.Reyes -- So how did you add the previous nodes??  Weren't they also added by "addBack"?  Or is there a function that adds nodes, it works, and instead of using it, you're writing duplicate code in the `addBack` function?

Comment: I  have an addBack and addFront function. Both worked before I used the tricimate function. addFront still works but addBack isn't working anymore.

Comment: @E.Reyes Which means that 1) `addBack` was always broken, or 2) Your `addFront` was always broken, or 3) Your function to remove a single node was always broken, or 4) A combination of 1), 2), or 3).  It has nothing to do with the function that I posted -- it calls your existing functions, and if they are buggy, then they need to be fixed.  You really need to thoroughly test your functions with **good** test cases to make sure they work properly.

Answer (score 0):

The function can be defined the following way

```
void tricimate()
{
    node *current = head;

    while ( current && ( current = current->next ) && ( current = current->next ) )
    {
        node *toDelete = current;

        current->prev->next = current->next;
        if ( current->next != nullptr )
        {
            current->next->prev = current->prev;
        }
        else
        {
            tail = current->prev;
        }

        current = current->next;

        delete toDelete;
    }
}
```

As for your function then for starters even its first statement is already wrong

```
void tricimate()
    {
    node * toDelete = head->next->next;
    //....
```

because in general `head` or `head->next` can be equal to `nullptr`.